FRANCINE, a rebus with a 5 letter answer
FRANCINE
The answer to this rebus is 5 letters long.

Let’s try going for

 Where I am right now, Paris!


 The text is written in capital letters, and consists of the words « in » and « France ». This makes me think of the capital of France - Paris, which is indeed 5 letters long.


+1 Wow!  That was quick.

I've looked at this several times and still don't think this rebus quite works (not criticising your answer, note) - if anything, the way rebuses work, this is "capital in in France" with two 'ins', which is clearly nonsense. I'd love to be corrected if someone has a more valid way to read this than mine. Thanks.

@Stiv I agree with you about the two ins.  My rebus is not as good as I originally thought.

@Will.Octagon.Gibson Ha, it almost works, and it's nice to be able to use a name/word in this way as a rebus by itself (and the answerer was clearly able to work out your intention) but yeah, there's just something that little bit off about it... Sorry!
